# Java Date to SQL Server datetime2 via Hibernate: getting ms rounded like datetime?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, datetime, datetime2

My Java fields are defined as Dates, and like some others I have run into the issue of SQL Server's datetime rounding milliseconds strangely (to the nearest 1/300 sec).  Accordingly, I changed my tables to datetime2(3) for proper ms precision.  Why is the rounding still incorrect when Hibernate saves a value to the DB?

The value looks correct in the SQL insert statement, but by the time it gets to the DB it is wrong.  For example, if I insert 2017-01-31 01:23:00.999...

during insert:

```
<BasicBinder>binding parameter [11] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Jan 31 01:23:00 PST 2017]
```

from select shortly thereafter:

```
<BasicExtractor>extracted value ([start_t11_80_4_] : [TIMESTAMP]) - [2017-01-31 01:23:01.0]
```

I've tried specifying the dialect as SQLServer2008Dialect instead of SQLServerDialect.  (I've also tried specifying a custom dialect overriding SQLServerDialect, where I register column types Types.DATE/TIME/TIMESTAMP to "datetime2".)

I've tried specifying columnDefinition="datetime2" in the @Column annotation for the Date getter.

What am I missing?  I feel like it must be possible to do this without changing the Java fields from Date to Timestamp, and without changing the DB columns from datetime2 to long...